# inside part of fingers

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

What do we call the inside part of a finger?

Like we see in the picture below.

Supposing the hand is facing a door. Can we say?

The inside part of the fingers and palm are facing the door.

Please note that I need to mention both, "inside part of the fingers" and "palms".

[image]

Comment: If you absolutely had to specify both palm and fingers, I'd say exactly that - 'palm and fingers'. The fingers are always in relation to the palm, so the gripping surface faces the direction the palm faces when outstretched.

Comment: "I need to mention both"  This seems unlikely.  While it is technically possible to have a hand with no fingers, or bend the fingers awkwardly, it is unlikely.  So you need to justify this claim.  Why do you need to mention the "inside part of the fingers".   Why would "The palm is facing towards the door" be unclear or fail to communicate in your situation.

Answer (score 6):

It's called the flat of the hand when you hit someone with it. What are going to do the door? If it's jammed you'd probably use the flat of your hand to get it open. Describing the photo I'd say, "the hand is raised, its palm towards the door". Or, in a story, "He raised his hand, *the* palm towards the door." When you do that the fingers tend to face the same way. Do you *need* to mention them specifically?

In a calmer mood, with no-one to hit and the doors working normally, I might use 'front of the hand' as Jack O'Flaherty suggests, but it's usually only used when you've already mentioned the back of the hand.

Answer (score 4):

All of that is the palmar surface of the hand, including the palmar side of the palm, and the palmar side of the fingers. It is also called the front of the hand.
The opposite is the dorsal, or back surface.
[eOrthopod Hand anatomy](https://eorthopod.com/hand-anatomy/)

Answer (score 1):

In medicine the ANTERIOR face of the fingers and the palm of the hand is called:

Volar

As opposed to the face considered Dorsal [1,2].

Regarding the fingers, the same reference can be used, but when you want to pay attention to the function or more specifically to the muscular components, you can also call it the flexor face of the fingers.

Firstly, I called the anterior face of the hand because all anatomical references are based on the Vitruvian man [3]

References:

1. “Volar.” Merriam-Webster.com Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/volar. Accessed 24 Apr. 2020 (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/volar)
2. https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Dorsal-and-volar-surfaces-of-the-right-hand-demonstrating-a-wristwatch-imprint-from-the_fig2_278732617
3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitruvian_Man